# How do I emit a double value with full precision?

Tags: yaml-cpp

The following code did not work for me.

```
double x = 10.0;
double y = 10.0
double z = 0.0;
out << YAML::Flow << YAML::BeginSeq << YAML::Precision(8) << x << y << z << YAML::EndSeq;
```

which yields [10, 10, 0]. I wanted, for example, to get something like [10.000, 10.000, 0.000].

Let me know how I can emit a double value with full precision.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It sounds like you want "fixed" notation, which isn't implemented in yaml-cpp. Please file a feature request on the project page.